Salta un Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected al ejecutar PDOStatement->execute()
Este es mi Código:
  include('../../config.php');

   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $password_user = $_POST['password_user'];

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_usuarios WHERE email='$email' AND password_user= '$password_user'";
   $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
   $query->execute();
   $usuarios = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   foreach ($usuarios as $usuario) {
       $email_tabla = $usuario['email'];
       echo $nombres = $usuario['nombres'];
   }

Pero aunque el mensaje me informa que se realizó una conexión éxito a la DB, me da este error:
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected in C:\xampp\htdocs\www.invendy.com\app\controllers\login\ingreso.php:16
Stack trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\www.invendy.com\app\controllers\login\ingreso.php(16): PDOStatement->execute() 
#1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\www.invendy.com\app\controllers\login\ingreso.php on line 16

¿Me podrían ayudar?

El mensaje de error indica que, si bien estás conectado al servidor, no se ha seleccionado ninguna base de datos contra la cual correr la sentencia que estás intentando ejecutar.
En las aplicaciones lo más común es indicar esta base de datos como parte de la cadena de conexión, al lanzar el constructor de la conexión.
Dado que no muestras el código que prepara dicha conexión, te dejo un ejemplo de cómo usualmente se haría:
<?php
$servidor = "localhost";
$BD = "MiBaseDeDatos";
$usuario = "usuario";
$password = "password";

try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servidor;dbname=$BD", $usuario, $password);
  // set the PDO error mode to exception
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  echo "Conectado";
  //Aquí ya puedes lanzar consultas contra la base de datos "MiBaseDeDatos"
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Error al conectar: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>

Como ves, defino el nombre de la base de datos en la variable `$BD` y luego la incluyo en la cadena de conexión...

Si no quieres o no puedes incluir la base de datos en la cadena de conexión, puedes lanzar una sentencia use al motor, de esta forma:
$pdo->query("use MiBaseDeDatos");

Después de esta sentencia, las consultas que ejecutes irán contra la base de datos "MiBaseDeDatos".
Adaptado a tu código, podría ser:
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_usuarios WHERE email='$email' AND password_user= '$password_user'";
   $pdo->query("use MiBaseDeDatos");
   $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
   $query->execute();


Gracias @jachguate, tu respuesta me ayudo a encontrar el problema en mi código.
